# Passing value to jquery created input field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to pass a value with jquery to the SKU input field from woocommerce that is generated dynamically when you click on the quick edit button in `wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product`, but for some reason is not pasting the value the field.

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
function quick_edit_sku($product) { 
    $string = generateRandomString(); // outputs a random string correctly
?>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.editinline').on('click', function(event) {
            var sku_val = $("input[name=_sku]").val(); // checks if there is a value
            var random = '<?php echo $string ?>';
            if (sku_val === '') { // if SKU field is empty than apply random string. Though this doesn't work quite well, only on the second time I click quick edit it returned correct
                console.log(random);
                $("input[name=_sku]").val(random);
            } else {
                console.log('Already has value SKU value');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<?php } 
add_filter( 'admin_footer', 'quick_edit_sku' );
```

Button + Firebug
http://postimg.org/image/oqdpkhqov/

Comment: CAN YOU SHOW BUTTON CODE AND WHERE THERE IS ERROR POINT THAT LINE PLEASE

Comment: @anantkumarsingh added a screen shoot.

Comment: No errors outputting in the console. console.log(random); outputs correctly a random string.

Comment: WOW 26 views and no one.

Comment: can you try `$("input[name=_sku]").html(random);` instead of `$("input[name=_sku]").val(random);`? in your if condition

Comment: @M.Doye Nope nothing appearing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the js is fired to soon, when you click "Quick Edit" wordpress sends an Ajax request to fetch the HTML for the quick edit options, so `input[name=_sku]` doesn't actually exist on the initial click. simply adding a `setTimeout` function before adding the value will work:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.editinline').on('click', function(event) {
            var sku_val = $("input[name=_sku]").val();
            var random = '<?php echo $string ?>';
            if (!sku_val) {
                console.log(random);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $("input[name=_sku]").val(random)
                }, 100);
            } else {
                console.log('Already has value SKU value');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also, your check `if (sku_val === '') { ... }` fails.

Using `if (!sku_val) { ... }` will however work.

(Tested on WP 4.1.1)